# How to check user is located in between the coordinates, MKMapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, coordinates

I had userlocation and a boundary.
And the boundary has 8 oordinates.
I need to check wether the user is in the boundary or not.
Am using mapview in iPhone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do this using some built-in functions in Map Kit are to add your boundary as an `MKPolygon` overlay to the map view.  Keep a reference to the overlay as an ivar.

Then whenever you want to check if user is inside the boundary (for example when user's location changes), convert the user coordinates to a `CGPoint` and retrieve the `CGPath` for the boundary and call `CGPathContainsPoint`.  There are Map Kit functions to do these conversions.

[This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474299/iphone-mkmapview-mkpolygon-issues/5474737#5474737) of mine gives an example of how to add an `MKPolygon` overlay and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354130/how-to-determine-if-an-annotation-is-inside-of-mkpolygonview-ios/4354250#4354250) has an example of the `CGPathContainsPoint` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Point Inclusion in Polygon Test](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html) to check whether the users location is inside or outside the boundary (polygon).