# Converting CLLocation objects to MKMapPoint structs

Tags: ios, ios5, mapkit, core-location, mkoverlay

I would like to create a `MKPolygon` to display on a `MKMapView`.  My problem is that I'm not able to figure out how to do it.

I know that to create an `MKPolygon` I have to create a bunch of `MKMapPoint` structs and put them into an array and call the class method `polygonWithPoints`.

My problem is that I have an `NSArray` containing `CLLocation` objects that have  `coordinate.latitude` and `coordinate.longitude` properties.

How do I convert it one by one to an `MKMapPoint` struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an `NSArray` of objects containing coordinates, it will be easier to use the `polygonWithCoordinates:count:` method instead of `polygonWithPoints:count:`.

The `polygonWithCoordinates:count:` method accepts a C array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structs.  The `coordinate` property in a `CLLocation` object is also a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

If you still want to use `polygonWithPoints:count:`, you can use the `MKMapPointForCoordinate` function to convert the `coordinate` property in the `CLLocation` to an `MKMapPoint`.

With either method, you first create a C array of the appropriate struct, loop through the `NSArray` to set each item in the C array.  Then call `polygonWithCoordinates` or `polygonWithPoints`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5474737/467105) has a code example using `polygonWithCoordinates`.  In that example, you would change the two lines in the `for` loop to:

```
CLLocation *coordObj = (CLLocation *)[coordinateData objectAtIndex:i];
coords[i] = coordObj.coordinate;
```

Don't forget to implement the `viewForOverlay` delegate method (and make sure the map view's `delegate` property is set).